# Reading file in segments of X number of lines

Tags: node.js, file-io

I have a file with a lot of entries (10+ million), each representing a partial document that is being saved to a mongo database (based on some criteria, non-trivial).

To avoid overloading the database (which is doing other operations at the same time), I wish to read in chunks of X lines, wait for them to finish, read the next X lines, etc.

Is there any way to use any of the `fs`callback-mechanisms to also "halt" progress at a certain point, without blocking the entire program? From what I can tell they will all run from start to finish with no way of stopping it, unless you stop reading the file entirely.

The issues is that because of the file size, memory also becomes an issue and because of the time the updates take, a LOT of the data will be held in memory exceeding the 1 GB limit and causing the program to crash. Secondarily, as I said, I don't want to queue 1 million updates and completely stress the mongo database.

Any and all suggestions welcome.

**UPDATE**: Final solution using `line-reader` (available via npm) below, in pseudo-code.

```
var lineReader = require('line-reader');

var filename = <wherever you get it from>;
lineReader(filename, function(line, last, cb) {
    //
    // Do work here, line contains the line data
    // last is true if it's the last line in the file
    //

    function checkProcessed(callback) {
        if (doneProcessing()) { // Implement doneProcessing to check whether whatever you are doing is done
             callback();
        }
        else {
             setTimeout(function() { checkProcessed(callback) }, 100); // Adjust timeout according to expecting time to process one line
        }
    }

    checkProcessed(cb);
});
```

This is implemented to make sure doneProcessing() returns true before attempting to work on more lines - this means you can effectively throttle whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use MongoDB and I'm not an expert in using [Lazy](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy), but I think something like below might work or give you some ideas. (note that I have not tested this code)

```
var fs   = require('fs'),
    lazy = require('lazy'); 

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('yourfile.txt');

var file = lazy(readStream)
  .lines                     // ask to read stream line by line
  .take(100)                 // and read 100 lines at a time.
  .join(function(onehundredlines){
      readStream.pause();    // pause reading the stream
      writeToMongoDB(onehundredLines, function(err){
        // error checking goes here
        // resume the stream 1 second after MongoDB finishes saving.
        setTimeout(readStream.resume, 1000); 
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: take(100) does not take 100 at a time, but takes 100 lines and passes them on in the chain. I tried having a look that used take(X), but that reaches a limit on event emitters and would not work.

Comment: did the readStream.pause() not help with this issue? I put it in there as otherwise your whole stream would be read in one go without stopping and you would end up with tons of function(onehundledlines) being called. It's crucial that you pause the stream somehow.

Comment: readStream.pause() and resume() made it stop entirely, and not resume again. I ended up using `line-reader` which did it a much more straightforward way that allows more finegrained control.

Comment: Shame the pause and resume didn't work. I thought the code looked pretty neat :) I wonder if this was Lazy's bug or readstream itself. What version of Node did you use?

Comment: It's an older version, so that might be related. I still feel `line-reader` when you want throttling and granular access to how fast you want to consume the data, however `Lazy` is definitely nicer if you want ease-of-implementation when speed / throttling is not an issue.

Comment: Added it, in pseudo-variant.